# HTML Form not passing date to variable

Tags: php, jquery

Hey im imputting a date using jquery date picker and its not passing the value i select. 
this is he code which is in the form. the rest of the form works but this.

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="contact-action.php">
<table align="center" width="450px">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>

  $(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
 <label for="datepicker">Todays Date *</label>
<input type="text" name ="datepicker "id="datepicker" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
```

and this is the code that presents the values

```
$today_date = $_POST['datepicker'];
$firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$age = $_POST['radio'];





echo "Thankyou for your providing </br>
Date: $today_date </br>
Name: $firstname $lastname </br>
Email: $email </br>
Telephone: $telephone </br>
Comments: $comments </br>
Age: $age</br>

An Email has been sent to the address you provided.";
```

im not the best at php so go easy

thanks all the best

Comment: FYI you have a typo in your example: `"id="datepicker"`

Comment: Output? What you get when you submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

remove space in name

```
name ="datepicker " to name="datepicter"
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

to

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("#datepicker").val(dateText);
    }
});
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`link and script`these things are meant to keep in `header` tag not in `table tag` move them from table tag

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jqueryui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>

  $(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body><form name="htmlform" method="post" action="contact-action.php">
<table align="center" width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
 <label for="datepicker">Todays Date *</label>
<input type="text" name ="datepicker "id="datepicker" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr></body>
```